# Cannot edit .json files in the Monaco editor within Cloud Shell (bug?)

Tags: monaco-editor, azure-cloud-shell

Cannot edit .json files in the Monaco editor from cloud spell.
Presented with error:

> File open error Unable to open file.json in editor. Insufficient
>   permission such as write access. Try again using a target with write
>   access permission.

Other files with the same permissions, from same directory e.g. *.ps1; *.md et al are unaffected by this problem.

Suggestions?

Comment: Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the regression caused by a recent code change. And now it's fixed and in progress deploying to other regions. It works well like this:

[image]